# Run Ant build.xml from PHP

Tags: php, ant, mediawiki

Is it possible to run Ant's build.xml from PHP or a web page?
Sometimes BAs wants to do the build and deployment and I want to make this available via MediaWiki page.Mediawiki is running on windows XAMPP.
Are there any MediaWiki plugin or any better solution for that?
Down the line I would like to pass some build.xml variables too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP's shell_exec() function can be used to call a command in the shell. So you could write a simple shell script that cd'd to the right directory, set any environment variables and triggered the build, then call that from PHP:

**do_build.sh** (lives at /home/user/bin/do_build.sh)

```
cd /path/to/build/dir
# Set any environment variables here
export MYVAR=somevalue
ant build
```

**myscript.php** (invoked via web page)

```
<?php
shell_exec("/home/user/bin/do_build.sh");
?>
```

UPDATE: Since you said that you're on Windows, here's the Windows-equivalent, using a batch file:

**do_build.bat** (lives in C:\do_build.bat)

```
cd "C:\path\to\build\dir"
REM Set any environment variables here
set MYVAR=somevalue
ant build
```

myscript.php (invoked via web page)

```
<?php
shell_exec("C:\\do_build.bat");
?>
```

Comment: The same thing would work on Windows, you'd just have a batch file instead of a shell script. I'll update the answer to show how you would do it in a batch file, but it's been a while since I wrote one :)

Comment: Can I pass variable values to the batch file too?

Comment: Yes, you can pass arguments. Everything between the quotes in the  is the command. So you could do shell_exec("C:\\do_build.bat ARGS GO HERE"), and that's the same as running: C:\do_build.bat ARGS GO HERE.